# How can I use OpenLayers in AndroidJS?

Tags: openlayers, androidjs

I have a small application that uses OpenLayers for some mapping purposes. The app runs fine on my computer with `npm start` (if I understand correctly, this runs `vite` to do the HTTP hosting; CMIIW).

Now I want to transform this application into an Android APK by using [AndroidJS](https://android-js.github.io/). However, I don't seem to get how this all works together. Javascript modules (which is how OpenLayers works) do not seem to be working in AndroidJS. For example, when I `import` my code in `main.js`

```
import { DriveMap, distance, bearing, rad2deg } from './assets/mod_maps.js';
```

I get this error when running that on Android emulator:

```
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE: /data/data/com.androidjs.webview/files/myapp/main.js:1
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { DriveMap, distance, bearing, rad2deg } from './assets/mod_maps.js';
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:                                                                      ^
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE: 
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
01-02 15:40:35.385 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:286:19)
01-02 15:40:35.392 15659 15778 E NODEJS-MOBILE: [ERROR:mailbox_manager_sync.cc(57)] eglCreateSyncKHR failed
```

Is there a way to use OpenLayers to not use Javascript modules, or how do I use Javascript modules in AndroidJS?

Comment: You can use babel, but unless there is a AndroidJS preset (I can't find it), you should be prepared for some touchy work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenLayers as "normal" javascript, by prepending all names of the classes with the full path:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
     layers: [
         new ol.layer.Tile({
             source: new ol.source.OSM(),
         }),
     ],
     target: idElement,
     view: new ol.View({
         center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon,lat]),
         zoom: zoomLevel
     })
});
```

This works for all classes in the OpenLayer libraries.